# Where are user ratings on audio tracks?

Tags: rhythmbox

I want to be able to rate songs in my collection in Rhythmbox player. But i cannot see such column.

What is the best case for me if i want to have ratings?

<strike>Is there players like mediaMonkey or JetAudio in Ubuntu with ratings and auto-playlists?</strike>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rating songs in Rhythmbox just means adding the ratings column to your music view.

Lets do just that...

swing  your mouse up-to either the global menu - or integrated menu and choose Edit - Preferences

[image: pic]

This reveal the Preferences window where you can select the Ratings columns:

[image: pic]

Ticking this rating column will add this to your Music Library view.  Just click on the stars to set your rating.

[image: pic]